# Can you answer to "Do you speak English?" with just "I do."?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

That's pretty much the question. It is a must to say "**Yes**, I do" for such kind of question or you can answer just as "**I do**".

Comment: Didn't there used to be a bunch of comments here?

Comment: You have many ways of answering in the affirmative or negative which are acceptable, including the "I do" you suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"I do" is definitely a grammatically correct answer. So are "Why do you ask?" and "None of your business" and "That answer is available (binary only) upon payment of the proper license fee" and "That's not important now" and "My hair is on fire!" All of these are *grammatically correct*. Whether they are *appropriate* answers is a different question, depending on the rest of the conversation.

The two-word answer "I do" is even the *best* answer when the question is more like "Who owns this tiger?" or "Who has the key to the tiger food locker?"